# NPCs claiming wrong house

Tags: terraria

In Terraria, the NPCs will sometimes claim my house, when their house is already claimed by them. I have them in a room that they can't escape from, but meets the requirements. Then when I try to assign them that house again, it just says that "This housing is suitable." and won't assign it. Any way to make them stop? (This only seems to happen when I use the magic mirror.)

Answer (score 3):

When you're in housing mode, you can move their flags around to move NPC residents to areas you see fit.